# SignInManager dependency injection fails with ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to get access to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager in one of my classes that is not a controller.

In Startup.ConfigureServices() I have:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>();
```

In my class I have:

```
public class Auth : IAuth
{
    ...
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

    public Auth(..., SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
    {
    }
}
```

And I get this exception:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'
>   while attempting to activate
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.AspNetUserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'.

Notice I'm not even referencing the passed `SignInManager` object in the constructor (I was but have removed it to simplify).  If I remove the `SignInManager` parameter from the constructor everything works fine.

All the relevant examples I have seen online end up being the case where the `SignInManager`'s specified user data type in the call to `AddIdentity()` doesn't match the user data type in the constructor parameter, but that isn't the case in my code.

Reading articles and example code for this makes it seem like this should be a simple task.  My constructor's other dependency injected parameters are working just fine except that I have the same issue if I try to inject `RoleManager` (except with a slightly different exception message).

Answer (score 5):

While you have added Identity, you haven't configured any data stores. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=visual-studio) you should be doing something like this:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

If you are using ASP.Net Core 2.1 however, use the newer version:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Comment: `AddDefaultIdentity` will create login/registration page for you right? I think `AddIdentity` can be used to avoid these prebuilt views.

Comment: @FCin Yes it also calls `AddDefaultUI` in addition to `AddDefaultTokenProviders` but that won't matter if OP already has the views in place.

Comment: @DavidG My users are stored in AD.  I have no interest in using a database table or the EF.  Also, I don't have a need for login/registration pages because of that.  Ultimately I'm trying to call the SignInAsync or PasswordSignInAsync method to log anonymous users into the application.

Comment: @DavidG And not planning to use cookies either.  I'm wanting to use Windows Auth for the MVC page and Auth API controller, but JWT for the remaining API controllers.  When a user comes into my Auth API controller from a non-windows device, they come in anonymous to an AllowAnonymous controller method in the Auth API controller and I want to call one of the SignIn methods so they are authenticated.

Comment: @JoeRattz: Then why are you using Identity? If you're user are in AD, then you need to either use Windows Auth or add something like ADFS as an authentication provider. Identity is for individual auth. You cannot use it for managing users in AD.

Comment: @JoeRattz Indeed, nowhere in your question do you even mention AD and is completely misleading for the reasons Chris mentions.

Answer (score -1):

User below if you are using asp.net core 3.18 version

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```